# How to get value from two dropdown and pass it to different url?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have two dropdown and want to get the selected year value of the first one and add it to the url of the header page and also to the second dropdown url options so that when I select a php page from the second dropdown I can see the year value on the page.

```
<?php    $id = $_GET['id']; ?>

   <form method="post">
    Report Period:
    <select name="year" id="year"  >
        <option style="display:none;"> Select</option>

        <?php

        $result1 = mysql_query("select year from year_data where id=$id");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

            $period= $row['year'];


            echo "<option  value=\"$period\">$period</option>";

        }
        ?>

    </select>

     Type:
    <select name="report"  id="report" > 


    <option style="display:none;">--Select--</option>


        <?php

    echo "<option value=\"".reportA.".php?org_id={$id}&year=\">reportA</option>";
 echo "<option value=\"" . reportB . ".php?org_id={$id}&year=\">report B</option>";

        ?>

    </select>
    <input type=submit name=button method="post"  onClick="getValues()"  value="view" >

</form>
    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">

    function getValues() {
var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
var report=document.getElementById("report").value;
    window.location.href = 'header.php?year=' +  year.options[year.selectedIndex].value
    window.location.href = report +  year.options[year.selectedIndex].value


       }


    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Why not just submit the form?

Comment: Set the action of the form to the next page, then you can access the form values from the next page using `$_POST`.

Comment: Are you okay using jQuery in the answer?

Comment: but the next page should be selected from the second dropdown so I can't have a specific page as the form action

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery but if it works I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**window.location.href** call will immediately redirect you referenced page. So 2nd call will not work.

What you need to do is ,

Lets say you have two page
page1.php <- say this has the code you have written in the question.

page2.php <- You can get values from the get vars. (See Below )

In page1.php change this two line

`window.location.href = 'header.php?year=' +  year.options[year.selectedIndex].value`

window.location.href = report +  year.options[year.selectedIndex].value

To

`yearValue = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value;`

reportValue = report.options[report.selectedIndex].value;

window.location.href = 'page2.php?year=yearValue&report=reportValue';

In page2

`report = $_GET['report']`

year = $_GET['year']

Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your code and I'm able to get the year and report value but the redirect part doesn't work.how can I show page2 as a popup window?

Comment: You have to give the full absolute URL, if are in local machine then something like "http ://localhost/your_project_path/page2.php..." or in a live domain then "http ://domain.com/.../page2.php".

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for something like this?

If I correctly understand what you need, there is no need to change your getValues() fn, as those values haven't changed - only the visible portion of the 2nd select.

Is this correct?

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RmwSt/)</kbd>

```
var yr;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selone').change(function() {
        yr = $(this).val();
        var txt;
        $('#seltwo option').each(function() {
            txt = $(this).text();
            $(this).text(txt + ' - ' + yr);
        });
    });

}); //END document.ready
```

Comment: should I have this on the getValue() function? it actually didn't work!